# how to install macos system truetype collection fonts into R?

Tags: r, fonts

Charter is a system font in macos.  Fontbook tells me it is in the truetype collection `/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/charter.ttc`.  Yet, for some reason, library `extrafonts` function `findfonts()` finds the ttf fonts in `/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/`, but seems to ignore ttc fonts.  Is there an easy way to use these truetype collection fonts, too?  pointers appreciated.

iaw

---

PS: Fortunately, in this particular case, I have a working alternative using the "Cairo" package to install the charter font from `/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/c0648bt_.pfb`.  this still works with

```
library(Cairo)
CairoFonts(regular="Bitstream Charter")
1. family: "Bitstream Charter", style: "Regular", file: "/usr/X11/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/c0648bt_.pfb"
> CairoFonts(regular="Bitstream Charter")
```

and then all drawing will use the Charter fonts.  However, this presumably will not work so easily with other fonts that are not in x11, too.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously solved a similar issue by using sysfonts and showtext. See if this suits your use-case:

```
library(ggplot2)
#install.packages("sysfonts")
library(sysfonts)
#install.packages("showtext")
library(showtext)

font_add(family = "charter", regular = "/System/Library/Fonts/Supplemental/charter.ttc")
showtext_auto()
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Charter ttc Example") +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "charter", size = 20),
        axis.text = element_blank())
```

[image: example_1.png]

### EDIT 1

The pdf device has restrictions on what font you can use: I believe it has to be one of the "PostScript font database" fonts (see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.6.2/topics/postscript).

To use the quartz device, you can change the font using `par()`, e.g.

```
TestChars <- function(...)
 {
   info = l10n_info()
   r <- c(32:126, 160:254)
   par(pty = "s")
   plot(c(-1,10), c(20,260), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
   grid(11, 24, lty = 1)
   mtext(paste("MBCS:", info$MBCS, "  UTF8:", info$`UTF-8`, "  Latin:", info$`Latin-1`))
   mtext(paste(LETTERS, collapse=" "), side = 3, padj = -2)
   mtext(paste(letters, collapse=" "), side = 3, padj = -4)
   for(i in r) try(points(i%%10, 10*i%/%10, pch = i, font = 5,...))
 }
par(family="Charter")
TestChars()
```

[image: example_2.png]

The cairo_pdf device can use other fonts, but it comes out bold (not sure why; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38545416/12957340) and many of the special characters in the Charter font don't appear to be compatible, e.g.

```
cairo_pdf(file="test.pdf")
par(family="Charter")
TestChars()
dev.off()
```

[image: example_3.png]

Comment: does this rely on ggplot2?  on my mac, without ggplot2, it has no errors, but the plain (xquartz) display is unreadable.   the pdf device tells me that charter is an unknown font family if I pass the familyname and ignores the charter font if I do not.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but overall it's a challenging problem. If you can share you intended use case I might be able to help you troubleshoot, but unless you have a good reason to avoid using your Cairo workaround I'm not sure if I can be any more help sorry.

Comment: the 'PS:' in my original message has a Cairo device working.  using the `CairoPDF` device then works.  but I guess truetype collections are not yet supported.  thanks for helping.  no worries.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Mac. I used the following code:

```
library(showtext)
font_add("Optima", "Optima.ttc")
showtext.auto()
```

Then I could use the font with:

```
family = "Optima"
```

Or this in the theme parameters to apply it to the whole graph:

```
base_family = "Optima"
```